# Size/Length and Type of a SQL table

Tags: sql, database, database-schema, database-table

How do I find the length and type of a column in a SQL Table Column?
i.e. While creating a table if someone used Varchar(20), I want to identify this information whether it is Numeric or Varchar and the length/size.

Also, can I reduce the size of the table without losing data.
For example, if all the data in the column is of size 15 and my column length is of size 20, can I just alter the table column length to 15, without losing data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query should work:

```
select DATA_TYPE, CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH, NUMERIC_PRECISION
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where TABLE_NAME = 'tableName' and COLUMN_NAME = 'ColumnName'
```

Per your second question, yes, theoretically you could alter the column length without truncating any of the data in that column. You should consider that any *future* data (which may be require greater length/precision) will be affected as well.

Answer (score 1):

Only select that table and press alt+f1 then you will get the complete structure of the table.